# "Reset my password" links to itself (page refreshes)

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I'm using WooCommerce.

When users go to the lost-password page, type in an email address and press "Reset password", the page just reloads. I'm not sure what wordpress normally does, but I would expect it to show a "email has been sent..." page or text.

The e-mail itself is sent just fine.

What could be wrong?

Similar, when the user creates a new password (by following the e-mail link), and  click on "save password" the next page is the lost-password page again! That's a bit confusing.

Answer (score 1):

I just found another solution to my problem. The problem was that the messages just wasn't displayed properly. By adding this code to my custom CSS (under "Appearance"), the messages are now shown again:

```
.page-id-1154 .woocommerce-message, .page-id-10 .woocommerce-message { 
    display: block !important; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution I came up with: we can override the WooCommerce template file and change it. I do not like overriding template files, because in the future the WooCommerce template might change and we have to copy it again and apply the changes to the overriding template anyway, but I could not find an easier way to do it.

From the WooCommerce plugin directory copy templates/myaccount/form-lost-password.php to woocommerce/myaccount/ into your (child) theme directory. (This is the way to override the standard WC template files)

Apply the following changes (that is: add the lines ending in "//added by Szabesz ?>" to the copy of the template file):

```
<?php wc_print_notices(); ?>
<?php $on_result_page = isset($_POST['wc_reset_password']) && $_POST['wc_reset_password'] == "true"; //added by Szabesz ?>
<?php $on_reset_true_page = isset($_GET['reset']) && $_GET['reset'] == "true"; //added by Szabesz ?>
<form method="post" class="lost_reset_password">

    <?php if( 'lost_password' == $args['form'] ) : ?>
        <?php if( !$on_result_page && !$on_reset_true_page ) : //added by Szabesz ?>
        <p><?php echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_lost_password_message', __( 'Lost your password? Please enter your username or email address. You will receive a link to create a new password via email.', 'woocommerce' ) ); ?></p>

        <p class="form-row form-row-first"><label for="user_login"><?php _e( 'Username or email', 'woocommerce' ); ?></label> <input class="input-text" type="text" name="user_login" id="user_login" /></p>
        <?php else : //added by Szabesz ?>
            <?php if ( !$on_reset_true_page ) : //added by Szabesz ?>
                If you want to use the form again, <a href="<?php echo esc_attr(wc_get_endpoint_url( 'lost-password', '', wc_get_page_permalink('myaccount') ) ); ?>">please click here.</a><?php //added by Szabesz ?>
            <?php endif; //added by Szabesz ?>
        <?php endif; //added by Szabesz ?>
    <?php else : ?>

        <p><?php echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_reset_password_message', __( 'Enter a new password below.', 'woocommerce') ); ?></p>

        <p class="form-row form-row-first">
            <label for="password_1"><?php _e( 'New password', 'woocommerce' ); ?> <span class="required">*</span></label>
            <input type="password" class="input-text" name="password_1" id="password_1" />
        </p>
        <p class="form-row form-row-last">
            <label for="password_2"><?php _e( 'Re-enter new password', 'woocommerce' ); ?> <span class="required">*</span></label>
            <input type="password" class="input-text" name="password_2" id="password_2" />
        </p>

        <input type="hidden" name="reset_key" value="<?php echo isset( $args['key'] ) ? $args['key'] : ''; ?>" />
        <input type="hidden" name="reset_login" value="<?php echo isset( $args['login'] ) ? $args['login'] : ''; ?>" />

    <?php endif; ?>

    <div class="clear"></div>

    <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_lostpassword_form' ); ?>
    <?php if( $args['form'] == 'lost_password' && !$on_result_page && !$on_reset_true_page || $args['form'] == "reset_password" ) : //added by Szabesz ?>
    <p class="form-row">
        <input type="hidden" name="wc_reset_password" value="true" />
        <input type="submit" class="button" value="<?php echo 'lost_password' == $args['form'] ? __( 'Reset Password', 'woocommerce' ) : __( 'Save', 'woocommerce' ); ?>" />
    </p>

    <?php wp_nonce_field( $args['form'] ); ?>
    <?php endif; //added by Szabesz ?>
</form>
```

By using these if statements we check the different states of the lost-password page and change it accordingly.

I expect the WooTheme devs to change this template in the future, since the default behavior is really confusing and I wonder why it is implemented in this way in the first place.